# How to send data

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use Extras to send data from ChronometerActivity to PlayerHomeActivity, but it doesn't work.

ChronometerActivity:

```
public class ChronometerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.chronometer)
Chronometer chronometer;
@BindView(R.id.fab_play) FloatingActionButton fab_play;
@BindView(R.id.fab_pause) FloatingActionButton fab_pause;
@BindView(R.id.fab_stop) FloatingActionButton fab_stop;
@BindView(R.id.btn_player) Button btn_player;
@BindView(R.id.btn_golkeeper) Button btn_goolkeeper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chronometr);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    timeWhenStopped=0;
    ChronometerListener listener = new ChronometerListener(this);
    fab_play.setOnClickListener(listener);
    fab_pause.setOnClickListener(listener);
    fab_stop.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn_player.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn_goolkeeper.setOnClickListener(listener);

}
```

PlayerHomeActivity :

```
public class PlayerHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int typePlayer = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("typePlayer");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_home);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    PlayerHomeActivitylistener listener = new PlayerHomeActivitylistener(this);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(listener);

    .....
  }
}
```

ChronometerListener:

```
public class ChronometerListener implements View.OnClickListener {
ChronometerActivity activity;
public ChronometerListener(ChronometerActivity activity) {
    this.activity=activity;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String typePlayer;
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.fab_play:
            activity.start(activity.getChronometer());
            break;
        case R.id.fab_stop:
            activity.stop(activity.getChronometer());
            break;
        case R.id.fab_pause:
            activity.pause(activity.getChronometer());
            break;
        case R.id.btn_player:
            typePlayer="0";
            Intent intent =new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), PlayerHomeActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("typePlayer", typePlayer);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_golkeeper:
            typePlayer="1";
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), PlayerHomeActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("typePlayer", typePlayer);
            activity.startActivity(intent2);
            break;

    }

}
```

I get this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: simonerusso.it.beneventoscouting, PID: 5963
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{simonerusso.it.beneventoscouting/simonerusso.it.beneventoscouting.view.PlayerHomeActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null
>   object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()'
>   on a null object reference
>           at simonerusso.it.beneventoscouting.view.PlayerHomeActivity.(PlayerHomeActivity.java:116)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: You are trying to get the `extras` before the `Activity` is created . so you need to put these line i.e : `private int typePlayer = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("typePlayer");` under your `onCreate()` method  to avoid that `null error` .

Comment: Check this annotation based library: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PlayerHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_home);


 int typePlayer = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("typePlayer");

BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.navigation);
PlayerHomeActivitylistener listener = new PlayerHomeActivitylistener(this);
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(listener);

.....
   }
}
```

moved below line inside the oncreate()

```
 int typePlayer = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("typePlayer");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getIntent().getExtras().getInt("typePlayer");` inside Activity's `onCreate()`